# selected text color cannot be seen in nautilus in KDE5

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, nautilus, configuration

In Kubuntu 16.04, when I select the text of the name of files, the selected text color is completely white and cannot be seen. How can I change the color of selected text in nautilus?

[image]

Comment: Which theme you were using?